# How can I open all videos in landscape?

Tags: java, android

How can I open all videos in landscape using following code? I want all videos to be open in landscape then change orientation according to rotating of the device's orientation from the last position.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
Set This Property In Your Manifest File On your Particular activity.
E.g-
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );